# Corona adding text on top of video

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a video in Corona:

```
video = native.newVideo( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, videoWidth, videoWidth * videoRatio )
    video:load( "http://www.coronalabs.com/video/bbb/BigBuckBunny_640x360.m4v", media.RemoteSource )
```

After that I have a text:

```
question = display.newText(questionText,100,videoHeight-50,native.systemFont)
question:setFillColor(0,0,0)
```

The text is shown OK, but when the video loads, the video stands over the text. I want the text to be over the video. Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks.

Cheers!
Serban

Answer (score 0):

It's because it is a native object and a native object will always appear in front of normal objects:

> Native text fields are not part of the OpenGL canvas and do not obey the display object hierarchy, so they will always appear in front of normal display objects including images, text, and vector objects. However, native text fields can be "inserted" (object:insert()) into Corona display groups and they will move in unison with that group.

I would try to use native.newTextField to see if that could be placed over another native object:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newTextField.html